# Split part of string after character, always same amount

Tags: python, split, python-re

I am looking to get part of a string after an `=` sign that will always be the same amount of characters, after the `=`.

Ex.

```
str = [<User id=000000000000000000 name='test' discriminator='0001'] -
```

I want to be able to get the `000000000000000000` and nothing else. The total length of the string may change, but the numbers I am looking to collect are always going to be 18 numbers, after the `id=`.

Comment: What's wrong with `(\d{18})`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = "str = [<User id=000000000000000000 name='test' discriminator='0001']"
id = re.findall(r'\bid=(\d+)\b', inp)[0]
print(id)  # 000000000000000000
```